# How Do I Pass Replies Between Actors in Play! and Akka

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I am using Play 2.0 and Akka to deploy a web application. I have separated actors based on responsibility, as such actors often need to communicate with each other during a single web request.

For example, given an actor that manages registered devices, it must query another actor that handles the associated user accounts:

```
class DeviceActor extends Actor {

  val accountActorRef = ...

  def receive = {
    case GetAccountByDeviceId(id:String) =>
      val accountId = getAccountIdAssociatedWithDevice(id)
      accountActorRef ? GetAccountById(accountId) map {
        case account: Account => sender ! account
      }
  }

}
```

When calling `DeviceActor` from my controller, I always get

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling `map` on a `Future` or `Promise` you are actually registering a callback. The reference `sender` is caught in the callbacks closure, but `sender` is only appropriately set while the `DeviceActor` is handling the message.

You have to capture the senders reference *before* the `receive` method exists:

```
class DeviceActor extends Actor {

  val accountActorRef = ...

  def receive = {
    case GetAccountByDeviceId(id:String) =>
      val X = sender
      val accountId = getAccountIdAssociatedWithDevice(id)
      accountActorRef ? GetAccountById(accountId) map {
        case account: Account => X ! account
      }
  }

}
```